# Error: codesign: unrecognized option --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal

Tags: facebook, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to follow this blog post (Xamarin.Forms) in order to get rid of the deprecated UiWebView reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

In one of the steps is asked to add extra *mtouch* arguments:

`--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type`

When I do so and try to compile I get the below error:

```
/MyPath/MyApp/MyApp.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/MyApp.iOS.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit: Error: codesign: unrecognized option `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type'
Usage: codesign -s identity [-fv*] [-o flags] [-r reqs] [-i ident] path ... # sign
       codesign -v [-v*] [-R=<req string>|-R <req file path>] path|[+]pid ... # verify
       codesign -d [options] path ... # display contents
       codesign -h pid ... # display hosting paths (MyApp.iOS)
```

Package versions:

- Xamarin.Forms: 5.0.0.2012
- Xamarin.Facebook.iOS: 5.6.0

Xamarin.iOS Build options:

[image: Screen-Shot-2021-08-24-at-8-34-22.png]

Please let me know how to proceed as I need to get rid of the UiWebView reference so I can upload my .ipa to the AppStore

Does a `Xamarin.Facebook.iOS` upgrade could help this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check your project to ensure there is no use of UIWebView ,if `UIWebView ` comes from third party libraries , update all of the packages , if problem persists remove the library and search alternative ,refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/webview#removal.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. However the Xamarin.Facebook.iOS is giving me trouble. It seems that it can't take the --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type argument. Fails.

Comment: If the problem persists in the latest package , I suggest you  use another package for  alternative .